# return the position of a list and to check if it exists

Tags: python, for-loop, position

I am trying (python) to insert a position of a list from the keyboard and if the position exists then it shows but my sentence is not working correctly

```
l = ['Poland', 'Spain','France'] 

variable=int(input('give me the position'))

for i in range(len(l)):
    if(i==variable):
        print(l[i])
    else:
        print('the position does not exist')
```

For example if I choose the position 2 it returns me 'the position does not exist' two times plus France  and if I choose a position that it does not exist then it returs me 'the position does not exist' three times

I also tried the next sentence but I insert a position that it is not in the list (for example 4) then it returns me IndexError: list index out of range instead of the print 'does not exist'

```
if(l[variable]in l):
    print(l[variable])
else:
    print('does not exist')
```

Could you help me?

thank you

Comment: Why do you need the for loop? `l[variable]`?

Comment: I also tried the next sentence but when I insert a position that it is not in the list like 4 then it returns me IndexError: list index out of range instead of the print('does not exist')

Comment: if(l[variable]in l):
    print(l[variable])
else:
    print('does not exist')

Comment: So handle the error. or you already know how to get the length of the list so just check if the variable is less than the length before attempting to fetch

Comment: the second code is better (no need for `for` loop) but `if(l[variable]in l):` does not make sense, you want something like `if 0 <= variable < len(l):`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use for loop, you can use try-catch as error handling. This is what you need

```
l = ['Poland', 'Spain','France'] 

variable=int(input('give me the position = '))

try:
  print(l[variable])
except IndexError:
  print("position does not exists")
```

Comment: better would be `except IndexError`... a bare `except` is generally bad code style (might obscure other mistakes in your code if you catch all errors)